# MySql using blob and clob Syntax error

Tags: mysql

Using mysql5.5

```
 create table Sail_Admin2(
 jobcode INTEGER(100) PRIMARY KEY,
 resumae CLOB)
 ;
```

Syntex error on `clob`
I have used the `BLOB` datatype & it said no error
Confusion is how to make `Clob` datatype
I am not getting any fruitfull result on searching on how to use the syntax
Can anyone tell what mistake is done here

Comment: Where in the manual did you find that `CLOB` is a valid data type for MySQL? See here for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

Comment: there is no such `CLOB` type.

Comment: Okay it is used int this way See the link http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/MySQL-CLOB-Columns-CREATE-TABLE.html Error removed usingLONGTEXT it will be able to accept my resumae

Comment: Even there it uses the plain BLOB variants. In your sample it was `LONGTEXT`. Please read first coment.

Comment: Also, using an int with 100 bytes is very ambitious. I would advice to use a BIGINT. This will store enough jobs for the next bazillion years ;)